# Missing addTo Method

Tags: java, grails

I am attempting to use the `addTo*` method in Grails one class to another. These classes have a many to many relationship. I have defined the `hasMany` in the first class..

```
static hasMany = [operators: Operator]
```

And have done the same in the other:

```
static hasMany = [matches: MatchDB]
```

And I have set the owner of the relationship:

```
static belongsTo = MatchDB
```

However, when I attempt to access `addToOperators`, as follows:

```
def matchDBInstance = MatchDB.get(result.matchId);
Operator operatorInstance = Operator.get(result.operatorId);
matchDBInstance.addToOperators(operatorInstance);
matchDBInstance.save(flush: true);
```

I am seeing the following error:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: footballservices.MatchDB.addToOperators() is applicable for argument types:   (footballservices.Operator) values: [footballservices.Operator : Op1]
Possible solutions: getOperators()
at footballservices.RestfulController.mapOperator(RestfulController.groovy:63)
at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:198)
at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63)
at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:53)
at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter.java:49)
at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter.doFilter(MutableLogoutFilter.java:82)
at com.brandseye.cors.CorsFilter.doFilter(CorsFilter.java:82)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

**I have tried..**

I've spent some time trawling through the internet. I have ran `grails clean`, which didn't help. I have also attempted to add:

```
List<Operator> operators;
```

to the `MatchDB` class, but this didn't do anything either.

I have verfiied that both `matchDBInstance` and `operatorInstance` are not null.

**Details**

I am running Grails 2.4.3, JDK 7 on a Windows 7 machine.

Comment: In your MatchDB class do you have methods that begin with addTo?

Comment: Nope. And we never have either.

Comment: @MeiravLeibowitz the `addTo*` methods are added by Grails to domain classes either at compile-time via an AST or at runtime via metaprogramming. They'll never appear in the source code of the domain classes themselves.

Comment: @Dónal Yes but if you've got methods that start with `addTo` it can interfere with this process. I think that was what Meirav was getting at.

Comment: @Dónal Yes, the ambiguity of the methods (their names) and of course with different parameters

Comment: are you running said code in a test or something similar "odd"?  the code itself looks reasonable and trying it in bootstrap worked for me.

Comment: and just to be sure: you have added the classes in `grails-app/domain`?

Comment: No I'm not running it in a test. Yes they are domain classes.

Answer (score 0):

This is a reported bug in Grails version 2.4.2
See https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-11579

I was running Grails 2.4.3 but was still experiencing this in my integration test.
Once I changed my integration test to extend IntegrationSpec, this problem went away.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that the both domain classes have the according `package` that they should. That should be the first line of both files. Did you create them with grails `create-domain` or just copy pasted?

You could make unit-test for both files individually and then together to see if they have other problem that is causing this

Also more information about the domain classes would be good, can you provide the whole code?

Comment: This does not really provide an answer to the question. If you need to request that much clarification from the author then you should leave a comment below the question instead - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).